# sftp script not running in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron, sftp

I have to get files from another server, using sftp.

I created a script that will cd to my directory and execute the sftp command. Since i'm not allowed to add rsa keys into the external server, i'm using sshpass to handle this situation. 
If i run the script in  my session, it works fine (but print what every sftp command on screen). If i try to execute va crontab , the sftp command is not executed, but everything else in the script are executed.

```
set -o nounset                              # Treat unset variables as an error

umask 000
cd /path/to/dir
export SSHPASS='securepass'
sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - -P9999 user@external.ip.address: << !
 cd REMOTEDIR
 get *
 rm *
 bye
!

# processing the files part
```

Comment: Add full path to `REMOTEDIR` or use path relative to user's `$HOME`.

Comment: Why do you believe that that would cause different behavior between interactive and cron use?

Comment: What's the output? + Does the cron run under the same account as you are using in the shell?

Comment: @Cyrus the full path of REMOTEDIR is ./REMOTEDIR , i don't think this is the problem, since it works when i execute manually.

Comment: @Scott the difference is that the files are not downloaded, nor removed from remote server

Comment: @MartinPrikryl nope, the root's cron is used to run the script .. i'll try to execute manually with root to see what happens

Comment: @FernandoCrozetta: I was asking Cyrus why he thought some values of `REMOTEDIR` would work interactively and not under cron. But you said, “If I run the script in my session, it works fine …. If I try to execute via crontab” it fails. If you were running it interactively under one account (e.g., your personal account) and running it via cron under a different account (e.g., root), you should have said so in the question. (Better yet, if it works under your personal account, that proves that it doesn't need root, and you should have tried running it in cron under your personal account already.)

Comment: @Scott i didn't realize that the user could be the problem... that's why i didn't wrote that on my question. i'm new asking questions here, my apologies.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The user was the problem. since i HAVE to run the script as root (not my choice...) i realized that you are correct. as root it fails to validate the host key. if you can post that as an answer, i can upvote, i can choose your answer, i guess

Comment: @FernandoCrozetta:  Well, it's not so much the user id *per se*, but the fact that different user accounts have different environments defined.  (Except, of course, lots of things that work for root don’t work for any other user — but, apparently, your situation is the opposite of that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that you run the cron job using a different account, than you are using in a shell.

That can make `sftp` fail for numerous reasons. One of them being that the account, that runs the cron job, does not have the host key in the `known_hosts`.

Comment: that's right, i've changed my code, adding two options from ssh, the sftp line now looks like this:
`sshpass -e sftp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oBatchMode=no -b - -P9999 user@ip: << !`

Comment: @FernandoCrozetta `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is a very bad solution. Do not do that! Host key checking is there for a very good reason: to protect your from [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: I'm aware of that. but considering that the files are not really sensitive, i don't think this would be a major problem. also, it's not pssible to add keys into remote server, and having to clean the entry on known_hosts will lead into the same problem.